# Collection: filter by created_at by local time zone? (or CreatedAtStoreDate)

Tags: magento

I have to filter a collection (invoice) by date to get all invoices of one month.

For example: the `create_at` date of one invoice (in database) is: `2014-04-30 22:27:30`

If I filter the collection:

```
    $dateFrom = '2014-04-01 00:00:00';
    $dateTo = '2014-04-30 23:59:59';
    $invoiceCollection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
        'from' => $dateFrom,
        'to' => $dateTo,
    ));
```

The invoice with this date will be in the collection.

There exists two kinds of dates:

```
$invoice->getCreatedAt()
```

And:

```
$invoice->getCreatedAtStoreDate()
```

In this case:

```
$invoice->getCreatedAt() = 2014-04-30 22:27:30 (UTC/GMT time)
$invoice->getCreatedAtStoreDate() = 2014-05-01 00:27:40 (local timezone)
```

Under Sales->Invoices "my" invoice will be collect under May. If I use

```
 $invoiceCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection();
```

the invoice is in "April".

So I have to filter my collection by `CreatedAtStoreDate` - but this is not a database-field.

**My question:**

How can I filter the order or invoice collection by `CreatedAtStoreDate`, so that the invoice or order with the date `2014-04-30 22:27:30` will be NOT in my April-Collection but in May?

Thanks for help.

Comment: any luck finding an answer for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some GET param to define local offset, then add this offset to dates in filter. It will something like this (I didn't test it):

```
/** 
 * GET param which allow to set offset between local and server timezone. Server timezone is GMT.
 * Examples: add ?gmt=2 in URL for set local time to GMT+2, ?gmt=-5 for GMT-5, etc.
 */
$gmt_offset = (int)Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('gmt');  
$dateFrom = '2014-04-01 00:00:00';
$dateTo = '2014-04-30 23:59:59';

if($gmt_offset > -13 && $gmt_offset < 15 && $gmt_offset != 0){
    $locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
    $date_from = new Zend_Date(strtotime($dateFrom), Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP, $locale);
    $date_to = new Zend_Date(strtotime($dateTo), Zend_Date::TIMESTAMP, $locale);   

    if($gmt_offset > 0){
        $date_from->add($gmt_offset, Zend_Date::HOUR);
        $date_to->add($gmt_offset, Zend_Date::HOUR);
    }else{
        $date_from->sub($gmt_offset, Zend_Date::HOUR);
        $date_to->sub($gmt_offset, Zend_Date::HOUR);
    }

    $dateFrom = $date_from->get('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    $dateTo = $date_to->get('YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');   
}

$invoiceCollection->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
    'from' => $dateFrom,
    'to' => $dateTo,
));
```